# Equivalent function to pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode in presto?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, presto

Would anyone know if there in an equivalent function similar to the pyspark function `pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode()` in presto?

I am trying to explode and array with its index. I am aware of the existence of `UNNEST()`. However, this does not store the index of the value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update - I have found the answer

```sql
CROSS JOIN UNNEST('col_wth_array') 
    WITH ORDINALITY AS t ('value', 'position');
```